# User number when clicking on profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, search

This is just a little post to signal that when clicking on our profile in the top bar, we can see our ID user in the search bar.

Even though we can clearly see it in the HTML of the page when clicking "inspect", I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: what is the problem actually?

Answer (score 8):

That's not a bug. It is very much a deliberate *feature*. The search box is pre-filled with `user:youruserid` to let you search your own content (or that of any other user, just by visiting their profile page).

Comment: Ok my bad, thanks for the answer ! I thought it was not deliberate and it was the id that we have in their db

Comment: It's right there in the user profile URL. Users have a unique UserID, usernames are not unique. The number is public so we can distinguish between different users with the same name.